# how to use Gesture Detector "onTap" to navigate to some other page?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i navigate from one page to another using gesture Detector ?
this is what i have done so far , i have also imported the login_page.dart but the gestureDetector is giving the error "undefined login_page"

```
 GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                pageController.animateToPage(
                  login_page,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                  curve: Curves.linear,
                );
              },
              child: Text("GET STARTED NOW"),
            ),
```

Comment: Your above code should be works fine

Comment: What is `login_page`? How & where you declared it?

Comment: @MidhunMP its the page  (login_page.dart) where i want the user to be sent once he/she taps on get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code in `onTap:` function. ***

> Change the 4th line of the code.

---

```
 GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                pageController.animateToPage(
                  HereIsTheClassNameOfYourPage(),//Please type the class name of your login_page class
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                  curve: Curves.linear,
                );
              },
              child: Text("GET STARTED NOW"),
            ),
```

Comment: isnt this the same thing as the one i posted above ?

Comment: Yes, but with a comment, please have a look there.

Answer (score 1):

flutter dev also has a sample article for this

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation

Answer (score 0):

Animates the controlled PageView from the current page to the given page.

The animation lasts for the given duration and follows the given curve. The returned Future resolves when the animation completes.

The duration and curve arguments must not be null.

Future animateToPage (
int page,
{@required Duration duration,
@required Curve curve}
)

Answer (score 0):

Your `GestureDetector` syntax is correct but you passed wrong argument to `animateToPage`.
according the flutter api docs:

```dart
Future<void> animateToPage (
int page,
{@required Duration duration,
@required Curve curve}
)
```

this will Animate the controlled `PageView` from the current page to the given `page`.

**Your `login_page` var must be a position of a page.** you dont declare it correctly.

more information: [animateToPage docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController/animateToPage.html)